# Selecting multiple inputs in React programmatically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I'm working on a project where the user could enter dollar amount *(it gets formatted and displayed)*. I'm using multiple input fields in order to show/format the input text.

**Question:**

> I want to make "selectAll" select all the input elements
> not just the input selected.

**Code/Demo:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/money-input-example-forked-nbp5t

**How can I programmatically achieve this?**

Would really appreciate your time.

Comment: What do you want to do with selected inputs? You can actually use `querySelectorAll` inside `useLayoutEffect` hook, but it's better to create a ref for each input element.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. can you give me an example @antlis

Comment: Check this sandbox, there are two examples one with `useLayoutEffect`, the other one with `useRef`, `useRef` is a kind of better approach as I mentioned.
https://codesandbox.io/s/money-input-example-forked-qig1l?file=/src/components/MoneyInputList.jsx

Comment: How can I use this to "selectAll" when users clicks on control + C inside the input.

Comment: Check updated codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/money-input-example-forked-qig1l?file=/src/components/MoneyInputList.jsx

Comment: Thanks @antlis .. What i meant was if i could select all the inputs via dragging them and then using control +C. Currently I am only able to select one input since it's a `input` field. :(  Appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Your question, description, comments are confusing. What do you want to do with `CTRL + C`? When a user focuses on input, then press `CTRL + C` it should enable drag for both (all) inputs, am I right?

Comment: Sorry if i am not being clear. I just want to do `selectAll`  for the entire thing (Drag and select using cursor or even control + A) so that user can use control+c or control+V to paste. Thanks for trying to help @antlis